# How do I return single orderid having same rank?

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the following output:

| Orderid | Time | State | Order_rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10.15 | mfr | 1 |
| 1 | 10.15 | delivered | 1 |
| 2 | 12.10 | picked | 1 |
| 2 | 12.10 | mfr | 1 |

Here I have ranked the order ids wrt to the latest time and put the condition in where clause "where order_rank = 1", but I want to return a single entry for one orderjobid, i.e. for orderid 1 I want to return the delivered state entry and for orderid 2 I want mfr state entry etc.

This is just a sample data, I have more than 1000s of orderids, how do I return single entry for the same rank?

Comment: is you database `mysql` or `snowflake` or do you need SQL that runs on both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you code looks something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT 
     order_id, 
     time, 
     state, 
     RANK() over (partition by order_id order by time) as order_rank
  FROM VALUES
    (1,'10.15','mfr'),
    (1,'10.15','delivered'),
    (2,'12.10','picked'),
    (2,'12.10','mfr')
    v(order_id, time, state)
)
WHERE order_rank = 1;
```

which gives the output you have.

Not the solution you are looking for, but you can move from the RANK and sub-select and WHERE to use [QUALIFY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/qualify.html) and hide the order_rank line:

```
SELECT 
   order_id, 
   time, 
   state
FROM VALUES
  (1,'10.15','mfr'),
  (1,'10.15','delivered'),
  (2,'12.10','picked'),
  (2,'12.10','mfr')
  v(order_id, time, state)
QUALIFY RANK() over (partition by order_id order by time) = 1;
```

But as userMT notes, you want to put a numeric ranking into the selection

like:

```
     case state
        when 'delivered' then 1
        when 'mfr' then 2
        when 'picked' then 3
        else 4
    end as state_rank,
```

so if you have it as a separate field, it's easier to read:

```
 SELECT 
     order_id, 
     time, 
     state, 
     case state
        when 'delivered' then 1
        when 'mfr' then 2
        when 'picked' then 3
        else 4
    end as state_rank
  FROM VALUES
    (1,'10.15','mfr'),
    (1,'10.15','delivered'),
    (2,'12.10','picked'),
    (2,'12.10','mfr')
    v(order_id, time, state)
  QUALIFY RANK() over (partition by order_id order by time,state_rank) = 1;
```

giving:

| ORDER_ID | TIME | STATE | STATE_RANK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10.15 | delivered | 1 |
| 2 | 12.10 | mfr | 2 |

but you can mash the case into the rank also:

```
  SELECT 
     order_id, 
     time, 
     state
  FROM VALUES
    (1,'10.15','mfr'),
    (1,'10.15','delivered'),
    (2,'12.10','picked'),
    (2,'12.10','mfr')
    v(order_id, time, state)
  QUALIFY RANK() over (partition by order_id order by time, case state when 'delivered' then 1 when 'mfr' then 2 when 'picked' then 3 else 4 end) = 1;
```

gives:

| ORDER_ID | TIME | STATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10.15 | delivered |
| 2 | 12.10 | mfr |

Answer (score 1):

you could try
`row_number() over (partition by Orderid order by State)` 
and select the first one

Comment: ROW_NUMBER will only assign a single row the value `1`, but if you have multiple equal options, you will effectively get random result, where RANK will give the equal rows all `1`. Thus seeing you have an non-stable sort problem.

Comment: If you're happy with a random result here because you don't mind which row you return, then this solution works. I don't have a timestamp in my data and so nothing to sort by, but this ROW_NUMBER() solution did do the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Extend your ranking to include not only the time, but also an expression of state, like.

```
Order time desc, 
     case state when 'picked' then 1
                When 'mfr' then 2
                When 'delivered' then 3
                ...
     End asc
```

This way we assign a sort order 1,2,3 to each state.

Edited to make it correct as per comments from @simeon-pilgrim (thanks)

Comment: if you edit your posts within a few minutes of posting, it doesn't show it as edited (which is I assume why you deleted you first answer)

Comment: also you have `'delivered' listed twice